# Crontab is not running python scripts

Tags: scripts, python, cron

crontab is not working, and I have 0 ideas why.
I have a simple python script that I'm trying to run every minute
when I run the file from the terminal, it's working with no problem.

```
from datetime import datetime
file = "log.txt"
with open(file,"a") as f:
    f.write(f"{datetime.now()}\n")
```

My crontab has the following line.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/cron_tester.py
```

I also tried

```
 */1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/cron_tester.py
```

I tried to restart crontab
I tried to change the chmod of the python script
I reinstall Linux with another distro - nothing works ^))

```
Cron shows it's working and active 
alex@alex:/usr/bin$ service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: >
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-09-26 21:16:17 EDT; 25min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 65102 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4564)
     Memory: 384.0K
        CPU: 1.694s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─65102 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P
```

Comment: I would start with investigating a log. For example: "sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON" 
Check if there is something there.

Comment: You said you tried more then one OS. What is the current Ubuntu OS you are running as you asked this question?

Comment: Currently I have 
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="21 (Vanessa)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"

Comment: this is from syslog | grep CRON 
Sep 27 07:11:01 alex CRON[73780]: (alex) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/cron_tester.py)
Sep 27 07:12:01 alex CRON[73787]: (alex) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/cron_tester.py)
Sep 27 07:12:01 alex CRON[73789]: (alex) CMD (/home/alex/Documents/GitHub/script.sh >> /home/alex/Documents/out.txt  2>&1)

Comment: Cron is running every minute as it should

Comment: Bash script has log that /home/alex/Documents/GitHub/script.sh: 5: python: not found
so does it mean I have wrong path to python? I'm using /usr/bin/python3 and if I try to search alex@alex:~$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Comment: `file = "log.txt"`  where is log.txt located? I miss a `cd` in the script so ... it won't be checked in `/home/alex/Documents/GitHub/`,

Answer (score 1):

Crontab issues are often caused by using relative paths. Try `file = "/home/alex/Documents/GitHub/log.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my machine, working fine. Try adding these two lines to the top of your crontab.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: thank you, I did and nothing changed, unfortunately